# Sharing data via a BehaviorSubject and binding to the results, not sure if this is alright?

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I am using a service to hold a some data I need to share across different components.
In order to make my html cleaner I have split my form into multiple components that holds a few fields.

Here's an example.

**Service :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private mAccount$ = new BehaviorSubject({accountdatahere});

  // subscribe to this
  public get Account$(): Observable<IAccount> {
     return this.mAccount$.asObservable();
  }

  constructor() { }

  SetAccount(acc) {
    this.mAccount$.next(acc); // this gets called my my parent component (not depicted)
  }

}
```

(Note: code is a example)

**Component 1:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  template: `
    {{account}}
  `,
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  account: IAccount;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.Account$.subscribe(acc => {
        this.account = acc;
        this.account.Name = 'Changed from Component 1';
     })

  }

}
```

**Component 2:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  template: `
    {{account.Name}} <<==== NOTE: ** (Over here is shows 'Changed from Component 1')
  `,
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

  account: IAccount;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.Account$.subscribe(acc => this.account = acc; );
  }

}
```

The issue I am having is that Component 2 reflects the changes made in component 1, without having to call 'Account$.next()'.

Is this a intended use of BehaviorSubject or am I doing something wrong? 
If I want to do it by use of '.next()' then will I have to have change detection on all input fields and then call '.next()' or is my design wrong and should I rather keep all my html in one component ?

Any advice ?

Comment: Could you try, in `component 1` to set `this.account` not directly to `acc`, but make a deep copy like for example: ```this.account = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(acc))``` and see what that does? My bet is that your shared state is sharing the reference, making changes made earlier reflect throughout the app as it's requesting the same reference.

Just a quick tip; avoid Subjects unless you have a good reason to use them. Most Observables can be created using creation operators. Prefer that over Subjects where you can.

Comment: I'm almost certain it must be sharing the reference, I'm not sure why though. Do you have any example of how I can do what you described?, how would I push changes to all components involved ?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do. But one direction would be to make your object `immutable`, aka not directly mutating it's state but creating a new object with your changes and `.next()`ing that over your `Subject`.

If you want all components to have the same values but not share state; make a deepCopy upon `next` (aka the JSON.parse/stringify example) or do not use a Subject that is a hot observable; instead create an Observable that has it's own instances. `of({ your: 'object'})` will do the trick in that instance.

But it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, I understand, Basically I have split a account form across multiple components, all of which create one big form together, they need to all share the same account and update their own fields on the account, I cant call `.next().` as I normally would when submitting because each component is only a part of the form. I'm assuming my design is possibly wrong with all the components ? or is there a way to do it like this ?

Comment: What you could do is create the `formGroup` on the top level (the smart component), and pass the parts of the `formGroup` (sub-groups) to the components that handle them. No Subjects, and you can just add validation and synchronize state on the top level smart component. You can even use that to do `patchValue()` to overwrite and all that!